# "SquashFS error: unable to read data cache entry". When installing latest 20.04 ISO from Ubuntu on VMWare Player, during EasyInstall

Tags: system-installation, vmware, iso, squashfs

I downloaded the latest 20.4 ISO (ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso) from Ubuntu.com and tried to use it to create a new VM in VMWare Player using EasyInstall, on Windows 10 Home 64bit, using default settings (20GB disk).

I have about 55GB disk space free.

I enter my username and password and the install begins.

Sometime after the 'Detecting filesystems' stage, I notice the screen showing the SQUASHFS error being spammed 100's of times a second.

Any ideas? I've tried running it several times over, even re-downloading the ISO in case it got corrupted somehow... I've had Ubuntu running in VMWare Player on this machine before, along with CentOS and Fedora.

[image]

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/495295/is-there-any-way-to-customize-vmwares-easy-install-of-ubuntu. Bottom Line: Don't "Easy Install" Ubuntu. It's already easy.

Comment: ok, not sure how it can be a duplicate when that question is on a different server. In any case, simply installing a different way doesn't fix the issue. Maybe the issue is with VMware, and that's fine. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I installed the Ubuntu ISO again and tried. and it worked. I think if you lose your internet connection while downloading the OS file it gets corrupted, that's why this issue pops up.

https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

I used this link